# Liferay model listener - on after update handler loop

Tags: liferay, listener

I have created custom model listener for DLFileEntry in Liferay 6.2 GA6. However, the onAfterUpdate method is called repeatedly even when no change has been made on DLFileEntry.

Let me describe the situation:

1. The file entry is changed through the content administration in Liferay
2. The `onAfterUpdate` method is triggered (this is OK)
3. The `onAfterUpdate` method is triggered again and again - even though there is no update made on this entry

I' ve dumped the stack trace when the (unexpected) update event happenes. It looks like the `onAfterUpdate` is triggered by `incrementViewCounter(..)`method, which is triggered by `BufferedIncrementRunnable` class

```
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
        at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1365)
        at eu.package.hook.model.listener.DLFileEntryModelListener.onAfterUpdate(DLFileEntryModelListener.java:63)
        at eu.package.hook.model.listener.DLFileEntryModelListener.onAfterUpdate(DLFileEntryModelListener.java:32)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy865.onAfterUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.BasePersistenceImpl.update(BasePersistenceImpl.java:340)
        at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.incrementViewCounter(DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.java:1450)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2034.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.increment.BufferedIncreasableEntry.proceed(BufferedIncreasableEntry.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.increment.BufferedIncrementRunnable.run(BufferedIncrementRunnable.java:65)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have read the documenantation about the bufferend increment in [portal.properties docs page](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Buffered%20Increment). It's not recommended to disable this feature.

I have also thought about checking if any relevant change has been made on DLFileEntry object in model listener method. I just wanted to check, if there is any configuration that could be made to bypass the `onAfterUpdate` method when it's triggered by `incrementViewCounter` method.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

On after update method:

```
private void createMessage(DLFileEntry model, String create) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("action", create);
    jsonObject.put("id", model.getFileEntryId());
    MessageBusUtil.sendMessage(SUPIN_MESSAGE_LISTENER_DESTINATION, jsonObject);
}


@Override
public void onAfterUpdate(DLFileEntry model) throws ModelListenerException {
    if (LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
        URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) (Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())).getURLs();
        LOG.trace("Current thread classpath is: " + StringUtils.join(urls, ","));
    }
    LogMF.info(LOG, "File entry on update event - id {0}" , new Object[]{model.getFileEntryId()});
    Thread.dumpStack();
    createMessage(model, UPDATE);

}
```

Here is the message listener (message bus) which performs the on after update actions:

```
private void createOrUpdate(DLFileEntry model, String createOrUpdate) {
    try {
        initPermissionChecker(model);

        LOG.info("Document " + model.getFileEntryId() + " " + createOrUpdate + "d in Liferay. Creating entry in Safe.");
        long documentInSafe;
        if (UPDATE.equalsIgnoreCase(createOrUpdate)) {
            documentInSafe = (long) model.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute(EXPANDO_SAFE_DOCUMENT_ID);
            if (documentInSafe > 0) {
                safeClient.updateDocumentInSafe(model);
            } else {
                documentInSafe = safeClient.createDocumentInSafe(model);
            }
        } else {
            documentInSafe = safeClient.createDocumentInSafe(model);
        }
        LOG.info("Document " + createOrUpdate +"d successfully with id " + documentInSafe);
        saveSafeIDToExpando(model, documentInSafe);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Unable to safe ID of document in Safe", e);
    }
}

private void saveSafeIDToExpando(DLFileEntry model, long documentInSafe) throws SystemException {
    try {
        ExpandoTable table = ExpandoTableLocalServiceUtil.getDefaultTable(model.getCompanyId(), DLFileEntry.class.getName());
        ExpandoColumn column = ExpandoColumnLocalServiceUtil.getColumn(table.getTableId(), EXPANDO_SAFE_DOCUMENT_ID);
        ExpandoValueLocalServiceUtil.addValue(model.getCompanyId(), table.getTableId(), column.getColumnId(), model.getClassPK(), String.valueOf(documentInSafe));
        LOG.info("ID of document in Safe updated in expando attribute");
    } catch (PortalException e) {
        LOG.error("Unable to save Safe document ID in expando." , e);
        ;
    }
}

private void initPermissionChecker(DLFileEntry model) throws Exception {
    User safeAdminUser = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByScreenName(model.getCompanyId(), SAFE_ADMIN_SCREEN_NAME);
    PermissionChecker permissionChecher = PermissionCheckerFactoryUtil.create(safeAdminUser);
    PermissionThreadLocal.setPermissionChecker(permissionChecher);
    PrincipalThreadLocal.setName(safeAdminUser.getUserId());
    CompanyThreadLocal.setCompanyId(model.getCompanyId());
    LOG.info("Permission checker successfully initialized.");
}
```

Comment: Can I see the code of custom onAfterUpdate  method?

Comment: @DanieleBaggio - thanks for reply. I have added the custom code to my post. I have suspected the ExpandoValueService to trigger the onAfterUpdate repeatedly, but this is not the case (I have  tested it with/without it).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this, but I am not sure if it resolves your case.

I've changed the body of your own method onAfterUpdate.

Using TransactionCommitCallbackRegistryUtil you can detach the model update request from the subsequent createMessage logic.

```
public void onAfterUpdate(DLFileEntry model) throws ModelListenerException {

    TransactionCommitCallbackRegistryUtil.registerCallback(new Callable() {

         @Override
         public Void call() throws Exception {
              createMessage(model, UPDATE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but this didn't help. The onAfterUpdate is triggered again and again :(